# I keep getting a unicode error message when running some os-module code on python(opening an mp3)

Tags: python, audio, unicode

[image: code written]

I've been attempting to get an mp3 file run due to python, but i can get it to work, I'm not sure whether the os module can't run an mp3 or i'm just missing something.

[image: unicode error message]

Comment: You need to post the code and error message into your question as text. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It could be the \ in the path.  Use a raw string:  `r'C:\ ... '`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the '\U' in '\Users'. The \u in python denotes unicode string. That's why you're getting the error. Place your file in some other directory or use r'C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Bass_drum.mp3'. For more on unicode, refer this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings